# If (see body for link) was too localised, where can I ask such a question and get useful answers?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/232815/ssd-aware-data-recovery-specialists-in-london-uk-closed) earlier today, but it was closed as being too localised.  That's fine, I guess.  However, where *can* I ask such a question?

Answer (score 5):

In the US it would be the yellow pages under "PC Repair".  A better example of a question that wouldn't have been closed is (unless it's a duplicate)... "Is there a difference between recovering data off of a Hard Disk drive or a Solid State Drive?"

Super User is a place where *anyone* can learn from your question.  When you ask a question about a specific area then that makes it too localized.

Comment: You could also drop by [Super User chat ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) and try asking there